# Create a aws Amplify app from source code

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I have done one of the tutorial for aws amplify (the todo app). When it was done I had no more need for it so I deleted the application from the cloud.

Then one though hit me. If I have the source code locally (or hypothetically in git) for my amplify application, can't I somehow recreate the app in the cloud again from the source? if I understood it completely it is supposed to be infrastructure-as-code.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Amplify CLI doesn't support this.

Amplify is not an Infrastructure as Code.

From the [AWS Documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/amplify/):

> AWS Amplify is a set of tools and services that can be used together or on their own, to help front-end web and mobile developers build scalable full stack applications, powered by AWS. With Amplify, you can configure app backends and connect your app in minutes, deploy static web apps in a few clicks, and easily manage app content outside the AWS console.

Even if it's not supported, apparently there is some way to add services to the newly created Amplify from the existing Amplify backend.

https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/3505#issuecomment-597897873

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer. I found the following command "amplify init --app <git repo>" which seems to be doing what I want except that it needs the code to the in a git repo and seems to have created a new backend environment instead of reusing the old one.

Maybe I misunderstood what they meant, but their tutorial said: "As you add features, the amplify folder will grow with infrastructure-as-code templates that define your backend stack. Infrastructure-as-code is a best practice way to create a replicable backend stack."

Comment: The url to the above quote didn't fit above:

https://docs.amplify.aws/start/getting-started/setup/q/integration/react/#initialize-a-new-backend